# Including modules using operator import

Tags: toit

I've read the "Package tutorial" section and, to be honest and frank, I didn't understand much. But I know exactly what I want to get.

1. I've two files, *bs_func.toit*, which contains the ***binary_search*** function, and *bs_test.toit*, which uses this function:

***bs_func.toit***

```
binary_search list needle:
  from := 0
  to := list.size - 1
  while from <= to :
    mid := (to + from) / 2
    if list[mid] == needle :
      return mid
    else if list[mid] < needle :
      from = mid + 1
    else if list[mid] > needle :
      to = mid - 1
  return -1
```

***bs_test.toit***

```
import ???
main:
  list := List 16: it * 2
  print "Binary Search"
  print "List: $list"
  number := 8
  index := binary_search list number
  print "index of $number is $index"
```

2. I just need to include *binary_search* in *bs_test.toit* by means an *import* statement.
3. Experiments with the *package.lock* file ended in failure, so I would just like to get instructions on how to do this in my case.
4. I am using VCS.

Thanks in advance, MK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you refer to package tutorial I'm assuming that you have the following layout:

- a package-folder. Let's say `bs`, but the name isn't relevant,
- the file `bs_func.toit` inside the `src` folder of `bs`. So `bs/src/bs_func.toit`, and
- `bs_test.toit` inside the `test` folder of `bs`. So `bs/tests/bs_test.toit`.

The easiest way to import `bs_func.toit` from `bs_test.toit` is to dot out, and then go into the `src` folder:

```
import ..src.bs_func // double dot goes from bs/src to bs/, and .src goes into bs/src.
```

To guarantee that only `binary_search is visible, then one can restrict the import as follows:

```
import ..src.bs_func show binary_search
```

A different (and probably preferred) way is to import the `bs_func.toit` as if it was part of a package (which it should become anyway).  (Note: I will change the tutorial to follow that approach).

You want to start by giving the tests directory a `package.lock` file, indicating that `import`s should use it to find their targets.

```sh
# Inside the bs/tests folder:
toit pkg init --app
```

This should create a `package.lock` file.

We can now import the package with the `--local` flag:

```sh
# Again in the tests folder
toit pkg install --local --prefix=bs ..
```

This says: Install the local (`--local`) folder ".." (`..`) as package with the prefix "bs" (`--prefix=bs`).

Now we can use this prefix to import the package (and thus the `bs_func.toit`):

```
import bs.bs_func

main:
  ...
  index := bs.binary_search list number
  ...
```

As you can see: just importing the file with `bs.bs_func` gives it the prefix `bs`. You can avoid the prefix by using `show`:

```
import bs.bs_func show binary_search

main:
  ...
  index := binary_search list number
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I used your instructions and find that simple import works without problems. However, if create a package, I have compilation problems.

Comment: Package functions have been added quite recently to Toit.
Maybe your version doesn't support all features yet. (It might even be that we haven't fully received all features yet). If the relative import works, let's stick to that for now, but eventually the package import would be better (as it tests the import the same way as other users).